# Update label based on Key in Dropdown menu Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am trying to update a label based on the key selected from a drop down menu (using a dictionary). I am unsure as to how i can update the label. Thankyou. I have made an attempt as below however I am obviously doing it wrong due to lack of knowledge.   Thankyou

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import csv


class DictionaryGui:
'''Display a GUI allowing key->value lookup'''
def __init__(self, parent, row, column, dictionary):
    self.dictionary = dictionary
    self.selection = StringVar()
    self.value = StringVar()

    username_label = Label(parent, text="Key:")
    username_label.grid(row=row, column=column)
    keys = list(sorted(dictionary.keys()))
    self.selection.set(keys[0])
    select = Combobox(parent, textvariable=self.selection,
                      values=keys,
                      width=8, command=self.update())
    select.grid(row=row, column=column+1)




    name = Label(parent, textvariable=self.value)
    name.grid(row=row, column=column+3)

def update(self):
    self.value.set(self.dictionary[self.selection.get()])





def main():
  window = Tk()
  test_dict = {'first_name': 'Fred', 'last_name': 'Bloggs', 'age' : 20}
  gui = DictionaryGui(window, 0, 0, test_dict)
  window.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import csv


class DictionaryGui:
'''Display a GUI allowing key->value lookup'''
def __init__(self, parent, row, column, dictionary):
    self.dictionary = dictionary
    self.selection = StringVar()
    self.value = StringVar()

    username_label = Label(parent, text="Key:")
    username_label.grid(row=row, column=column)
    keys = list(sorted(dictionary.keys()))
    self.selection.trace('w', self.update)  ## Added this line
    self.selection.set(keys[0])
    select = Combobox(parent, textvariable=self.selection,
                      values=keys,
                      width=8)
    select.grid(row=row, column=column+1)

    name = Label(parent, textvariable=self.value)
    name.grid(row=row, column=column+3)

def update(self, *a):
    self.value.set(self.dictionary[self.selection.get()])

def main():
  window = Tk()
  test_dict = {'first_name': 'Fred', 'last_name': 'Bloggs', 'age' : 20}
  gui = DictionaryGui(window, 0, 0, test_dict)
  window.mainloop()

main()
```

What I did was simply attach a `trace()` method to StringVar and removed the `command` parameter that you were passing.